# Cyclic redirection in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, no-www, trailing-slash

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteBase /

# redirect all www-requests to no-www
# -
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect all home pages to / (root)
# -
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.(php|html?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

# remove trailing slash from dirs
# -
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# automatically add index.php when needed
# -
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|login\.php|reg\.php|robots\.txt|css/|js/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

The .htaccess file should do the following (for SEO):

1. Conversion to no-www (`http://www.site.com` should become `http://site.com`)
2. All URIs with trailing slashes should convert to no-trailing-slash: `http://site.com/me/` should be redirected `http://site.com/me`
3. All URIs with `index.php/index.html` should convert to just nothing: `http://site.com/admin/index.php` or `http://site.com/admin/` should be eventually displayed as `http://site.com`

However the current version of .htaccess results in a cyclic redirection when trying to access (`http://site.com/admin`). The real document that should be fetched by browser is `http://site.com/admin/index.php`.

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a module called **mod_dir** that's automatically loaded and it causes requests for directories that are missing the trailing slash to get redirected with a trailing slash. You can turn this off using the [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive, but note the security warning when you turn it off. There's an information disclosure security issue if you turn it off and default indexes won't get loaded. However, your lats rule (looks like) it does that, though incorrectly.

First, turn off the `DirectorySlash`

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Then you need to change the last rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/index.php [L]
```